# how to check DataGridCheckBoxColumn checkbox on button click event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How to check the DataGridCheckBoxColumn on button click. So when I fire a button click event I want the DataGridCheckBoxColumn to be checked.

```
 private void loadCheckBoxColumn()
    {
        MedicationDatagrid.Columns.Add( new DataGridCheckBoxColumn
         {
            Header = "Selected",
            Binding = new Binding( "checkBox" )

           } );
    }
```

**Button Click Event:**

```
 private void btnchecked_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {

        AwaitingMeds checkedItem = new AwaitingMeds();
        List<AwaitingMeds> awaitingMedslist = MedicationDatagrid.ItemsSource as                   List<AwaitingMeds>;
        buttonClickCheckedUnChecked();
        if( !( ( AwaitingMeds )MedicationDatagrid.SelectedItem == null ) )
        {
            checkedItem.checkBox = true;

        }

    }
```

**buttonClickCheckedUnChecked:**

```
   private void buttonClickCheckedUnChecked()
    {

        AwaitingMeds checkedItem = new AwaitingMeds();

        if( checkedItem.checkBox == true )
        {


            btnunChecked.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {

            btnunChecked.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use the normal WPF-CkeckBox in a ColumnTemplate. Then simple bind the CheckBox to your ItemSource and go throught it.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ist aktiv" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActiveBool}" Click="myIsActiveCheckBox_Click" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: How do I bind it to the item source?

Comment: I need to set the actual tick to be selected on button click

Comment: You don't need to set the actual tick. Set the boolean that the checkbox is bound to true and notifyproperty changed

Comment: How do I bind the item source to the checkbox?

Comment: I've been using wpf datagrids for a long time and I've always been annoyed with the checkboxcolumns two-click-check. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

On button click event

```
static int SelectColumnIndex = 0;
PerformAction_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
string data = string.Empty;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in MyDataGridView.Rows)
{
  if(row.Cells[SelectColumnIndex].Value!=null &&
         Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[SelectColumnIndex].Value) == true)
  {
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
      if(cell.OwningColumn.Index!= SelectColumnIndex)
      {
        data+= (cell.Value + " ") ; // do some thing
      }
    }
    data+="\n";
  }
 }
 MessageBox.Show(data, "Data");
 }
```